# CScript and VBS to Remove Line Breaks from Text File

Tags: vbscript, line-breaks, wsh

I have a batch file running which spits out a text/html file.  The batch file is causing some line breaks in the text file, which do not translate very well in opening the file in an email.  I have been trying to read up on CScript to create a vbs script that can read the text file and strip out the line breaks but have had no luck.  Any advice?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure how you'd prefer to do it, but this script takes a filename as an argument and writes the results to the same file.

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Dim fs, txt, contents

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set txt = fs.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(0), ForReading)
contents = txt.ReadAll
txt.Close

contents = Replace(contents, vbCr, "")
contents = Replace(contents, vbLf, "")

Set txt = fs.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(0), ForWriting)
txt.Write contents
txt.Close
```