# Batch File: Removing carriage return from .tsv file

Tags: file, batch-file

I am trying to remove carriage return from .tsv file using batch file.
This is how my .tsv file looks, the first line is a column line

*** **[CR]** and **[LF]** shown in these lines are manually added to get an idea

```
Class   Name & Address  Item    lbs Value   Pickup/Drop off Date:   23 Sep[CR][LF]
Class1  Ben Coha[CR]
 2305 E LA st[CR]
 VISIA, PA[CR]
 932112-4422    Health and beauty product / cologne body wear for men   0.13    19[CR][LF]      
Class2  mich marce[CR]
 255 rid court[CR]
 prince frick, PA[CR]
 20442  health and beauty product / cologne body wear for women 1.5 47
```

I want this file as below [I used notepad to remove('replace' by nothing) occurrences of [CR] only]

```
Class   Name & Address  Item    lbs Value   Pickup/Drop off Date:   23 Sep[LF]
Class1  Ben Coha 2305 E LA st VISIA, PA 932112-4422 Health and beauty product / cologne body wear for men   0.13    19[LF]      
Class2  mic marce 255 rid court prince frick, PA 20442  health and beauty product / cologne body wear for women 1.5 47
```

I tried following batch file. file is being put in one single line. It removes both carriage return and line feed.

```
@echo off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (myFile.tsv) do (
echo/|set /p ="%%a%"
)>>newMyFile.tsv
```

The result looks like..

```
Class   Name & Address  Item    lbs Value   Pickup/Drop off Date:   23 SepClass1    Ben Coha 2305 E LA st VISIA, PA 932112-4422 Health and beauty product / cologne body wear for men   0.13    19      Class2  mic marce 255 rid court prince frick, PA 20442  health and beauty product / cologne body wear for women 1.5 47
```

I want to modify the .bat file so that it only removes \r instead of removing both \r\n

Update: Somehow I am able to add images, this will give clearer idea. 
Similar .tsv file 
[image] 
want it to be like this
[image]

Comment: You'll have to use a vbscript/powershell for that (it's still can be embedded in a batch file). For example, use [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2975775/3959875) to replace `vbCr` with `" "` and then `" "+vbLf` with `vbCrLf`.

Comment: Are the records correct?  Record one has a space at the start and record two doesn't have a space.  Can you provide a few more records or confirm that records don't necessarily start in column 1?

Comment: It was a typo while posting, record one has no space. I corrected it.

Comment: Ahh :-) all is finally clear now that you incorporated [CR] and [LF] into the listed files.

Comment: Apologize for the miscommunication on my part, I guess the question is now more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trivial if you use the [JREPL.BAT regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044)

```
jrepl \r "" /f "myFile.tsv" /o "newMyFile.tsv"
```

You can overwrite the original file if you use `/o -`.

You must use `CALL JREPL` if you put the command within a batch script.

---

***Below is my original answer for when I thought there was a CR/LF at the end of each line in the source file (before the question was edited).***

I hate editing text files with batch, as it requires a lot of arcane knowledge, has many restrictions, and the result is slow. However, it is possible to solve this with batch, and I decided I could use the practice :-)

The following works provided that each input line is <= 1021 bytes long, and the output lines are all < ~8191 bytes long.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "input=test.txt"
set "output=out.txt"

:: Define LF to contain a linefeed character
set ^"LF=^

^"  The empty line above is critical - DO NOT REMOVE

:: Determine how many sets of 4 lines must be read
for /f %%N in ('find /c /v "" ^<"test.txt"') do set /a cnt=%%N/4

<"!input!" >"!output!" (

  %= Read and write the first line =%
  set "ln="
  set /p "ln="
  <nul set /p "=!ln!!LF!"

  %= Outer loop iterates the 4 line sets =%
  for /l %%N in (1 1 !cnt!) do (

    %= Initialize out line to empty =%
    set "out="

    %= Inner loop appends next 4 lines into out =%
    for /l %%n in (1 1 4) do (
      set "ln="
      set /p "ln="
      set "out=!out!!ln!"
    )

    %= Write the line =%
    <nul set /p "=!out!!LF!"
  )
)
```

Comment: It removed CR from the file but replaced it with LF as....                                      For the first line, it replaced CR LF with LF --- That is OK                                  For other record lines (from second line), it replaced CR with LF-- Here we just want to remove CR (replace with nothing).

Comment: @Vik - I tested with the sample input provided in your question, and it generated the requested output, with only LF at the end of each line. So I am at a loss as to what else you expect?! Perhaps you should edit your question to indicate where the CR and LF are in your source file (use `\r` and `\n`).

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I tried to attach screenshots with CR and LF displayed from notepad++ while posting the question but it said that I do not have enough reputation points to do so. I will edit my question to show LF/CR. One again sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Can you live with an empty first line?

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
  for /f "delims=" %%a in (myFile.tsv) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    if "!line:~0,1!" neq " " (
      echo(!newline!
      set "newline=!line!"
    ) else (
      set "newline=!newline!!line!"
    )
  )
  echo(!newline!
)>newMyFile.tsv
```

Comment: It removed (deleted) the first line from the file. \r and \n unchanged in the file.

Comment: The empty first line is easy to eliminate: `if defined newline echo(!newline!`

Comment: This script will fail if file contains `!`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this works for you, it simply replaces all `CR` with nothing.

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq" %%C in (`copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul`) DO (
    for /F "delims=" %%L in (myFile.tsv) do (
      set "line=%%L"
      if defined line (
          setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
          echo(!line:%%C=!
          endlocal
      ) ELSE echo(
    )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: +1, but why not move the `setlocal disableDelayedExpansion` out of the loop so you only need one toggle within the loop?

Comment: @dbenham It only toggles once, as it's in the outer loop, but you are still right, it's better for visibility to move it