# How to disable or delete the new line (CRLF) that is added after a command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, newline

when I try `"dir"` I get:

```
02/13/2020  03:29 PM    <DIR>          Saved Games
02/13/2020  03:29 PM    <DIR>          Searches
02/16/2020  12:57 PM    <DIR>          Videos
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
              16 Dir(s)  21,887,438,848 bytes free
  <<<<<<<this new line is what I want to delete or disable
```

I tried commands like
`findstr "." test.txt > output.txt`
but they all add that new line at the end.

Thank you

**EDIT:**
I export `"dir /B" to a file > output.txt`

I need this because another program uses the list, and the last new line crashes it.

The program that loops through that list is hardcoded, so I need to provide it a list without the blank line.

Comment: CR/LF is added after *EACH* command output. It's possible to strip it, but why? The solution depends on your use case, do you only show the output or want to store it into a file, do you want to process it with ... ? Can leading spaces be stripped?

Comment: Please edit the question to include at least one use case. (Why do you need this?)

Comment: Are you trying to run this through a for loop to get the number of bytes free?

Comment: There is no empty line, the last line simply ends with a CR/LF. Do you need the last line `16 Dir(s) ....` , else you could filter it by using `findstr /V "Dir(s)"`

Comment: @jeb commands like `cd.` or `set /A 15/5` dont

Comment: @HackingAddict0302 `cd.` output no lines at all, but without lines there can't be a line terminator

Comment: See [Batch File: Removing carriage return from .tsv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868862/batch-file-removing-carriage-return-from-tsv-file)